# Safari home screen user-agent string?

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, user-agent

Is there a specific "Home screen" or "app mode" user-agent string for Safari on IOS? I noticed that there is a bug on IOS8 that makes the browser window appear in the wrong position. Notably the time and battery info on the iPad will be visible over the webpage and a black border will appear at the bottom. I'm guessing that the panel that used to be at the top on IOS7 was removed out of some reason and this was not tested accurately.

[image: Note the info text covers the page and the bottom is black]

I would like to be able to work around these kinds of issues in the future so therefore it would be nice with a specific "App mode" user agent that could be used to fix bugs temporarily. Is there such a user-agent string or am I left in without workaround options?

I noticed this only occurs if the webpage is in "full screen" For instance the problem does not show up on stack overflow but it does on Slashdot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't sniff the user agent. A better way is to check the 'navigator.standalone' property. This will be 'true' when your web app is launched from the home screen.

I'm not sure why there's a black bar at the bottom here (that's definitely a bug), but in the future your content should be prepared to deal with the status bar, just like native apps do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is 2 of user-agent strings using IOS 8:

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/538.34.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12A4265u

Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/538.34.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12A4265u

hope it helps.

Comment: Is for one of them for app mode? It looks like its iphone and ipad only. It would be nice to know if the app mode one is the same?

Answer (score 0):

iPad and iPhone do not show "Safari" in their user-agent string when in HomeScreen mode.

Example of iPhone (viewing page in Browser) :

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13F69 Safari/601.1

And the same phone (viewing the same page in WebApp) :

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/13F69